# py2app will not include PySide modules

Tags: python, pyside, py2app

Simple hello world QT python script. Works fine from the command line. When I package it i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jquick/bin/dist/gui.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 340, in <module>
    _run('/Users/jquick/bin/gui.py')
  File "/Users/jquick/bin/dist/gui.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 336, in _run
    execfile(scriptpath, globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/jquick/bin/gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PySide.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named PySide.QtCore
2012-06-02 00:23:04.823 gui[4835:707] gui Error
```

So it sounds like its not including the module.. but ive tried including it in both the setup.py and the command line. nothing works :(

setup.py:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['gui.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['PySide.QtCore', 'PySide.QtGui']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

i've tried creating with both the --alias option and without. Even tried labeling them as packages. But nothing I do seems to include them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can Python find PySide.QtCore? At the command line type:

   from PySide.QtCore import *
2. If (1) works then make sure the Python version your invoking when executing py2app at the command line is the same Python version you're using at step (1). Some operating systems such as Mac OS X come installed with an older version of Python, and if your application works correctly when invoking it at the command line, then be sure you're not invoking a totally different version of python when trying to build your app.